# WikipediaR: How to automate a function with contribs()?

Tags: r, wikipedia

I'm looking to gather information on the contributors from a list of 1905 Wikipedia articles, including the number of contributors per page.

Currently, I can make a working script for one page's number of contributors.

```
library(WikipediaR)
contribsWiki <- contribs(domain = "fr", page = 5916592)
contribsWiki2 <- contribsWiki[["contribs"]]
nrow(contribsWiki2)
```

How can I automate the process for all the other Wikipedia pages?

I have tried tidyverse's apply() but it seems I'm always hitting a wall.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you're after:

```
out <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:nrow(list_of_articles)){
id <- list_of_articles[i]
contribsWiki <- contribs(domain = "fr", page = id)
contribsWiki2 <- contribsWiki[["contribs"]]
no_of_contribs <- nrow(contribsWiki2)
out <- rbind(out,data.frame(id,no_of_contribs))
}
```